# Google Maps Autocomplete Function with PHPRunner

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I'm designing an interface with PHPrunner that runs on XAMPP.
In a page of the interface I need to use the Google Maps Autocomplete function on a textbox.

To get the JavaScript piece of code I used this [guide](http://jon.kim/how-to-add-google-maps-autocomplete-search-box/). I managed easily to link the function to the Control of the textbox but as soon that the pages load the whole textbox crashes with Google giving an anonymous error (something like "We're sorry, an error occurred").

In particular I put

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

in the `<head>` tag of the page and the code

```
function init() {
            var input = document.getElementById('myfield');
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        }
```

in the Javascript OnLoad Event (in PHPrunner).

Comment: Google map not load properly

Comment: It's probably because of that, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Post your full code

Answer (score 0):

**Your Script:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

**Generate new key for web and paste your key in below script**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places
        async defer></script>
```